# Using custom OTF fonts in ggplot2

Tags: r, macos, fonts, ggplot2, typeface

I need to use a custom font, namely "Archer", with ggplot2 in R. Archer is an otf typeface installed on my system (Mac OSX Yosemite).

This script (found here: [Modifying fonts in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094094/modifying-fonts-in-ggplot2)) doesn't work for Archer, but works fine with other fonts such as Arial.

```
install.packages("extrafont");library(extrafont)
font_import("Archer")
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1:10)+theme(text=element_text(family="Archer"))
```

Is there something wrong with otf typefaces in particular?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to convert Archer from an OTF to a TTF. From `extrafont`'s [github readme](https://github.com/wch/extrafont):

> Presently it allows the use of TrueType fonts with R

I'm amused---I had to do this because my organization also uses Archer. The first hit for [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+otf+to+ttf&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS508US508&oq=convert+otf+to+ttf&aqs=chrome..69i64j0l5.2871j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) is purple, so probably that's what I used and it worked just fine.

When having trouble with `extrafont` it can also be useful to check the available options with `fonts()`. Then you can verify that your import was successful.

If you save your plot to a PDF, to make sure to embed the fonts as well, using `grDevices::embedFonts` or `extrafont::embed_fonts`.

Answer (score 21):

You can try the [showtext](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext) package, which directly works on OTF fonts.

```
library(showtext)
font.add("Archer", "Archer.otf")
showtext.auto()
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1:10)+theme(text=element_text(family="Archer"))
```

Please replace "Archer.otf" by the real **filename** of your Archer font in the system.

Using `showtext` does not require embedding the fonts.