# Adding Fonts to R using extrafont or showtext libraries (on Mac via FontBook)

Tags: r, fonts, truetype, extrafont, showtext

Two years ago I posted a related post:
[Add font to R that is not in extrafonts library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251290/add-font-to-r-that-is-not-in-extrafonts-library). With a better understanding of how fonts works, I now have a new set of fonts that I need to upload into R to use with `ggplot`. Despite the useful answers in the previous post, I'm running into a new set of issues:

First, I cannot load the `showtext` library. After reinstalling and loading the library, I receive this error message:

```
>   library(showtext)
Loading required package: sysfonts
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sysfonts’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'sysfonts', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘sysfonts’ could not be loaded
```

...and when I try to load the `sysfonts` library, I receive the following:

```
> library(sysfonts)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sysfonts’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'sysfonts', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I am not sure how to fix this `unable to load shared object` error, and as a result I've mostly given up on using `showtext`, as I cannot get it loaded into R.

Moving onto `extrafont` then, I run the following, to import fonts from my Mac into R:

```
> library(extrafont)
> font_import() # import all fonts on my system
Importing fonts may take a few minutes, depending on the number of fonts and the speed of the system.
Continue? [y/n] y
Scanning ttf files in /Library/Fonts/, /System/Library/Fonts, ~/Library/Fonts/ ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
/Library/Fonts/Andale Mono.ttf => /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/extrafontdb/metrics/Andale Mono
/Library/Fonts/Apple Chancery.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
/Library/Fonts/AppleGothic.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
/Library/Fonts/Arial Black.ttf => /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/extrafontdb/metrics/Arial Black
...
...
Found FontName for 63 fonts.
Scanning afm files in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/extrafontdb/metrics
Writing font table in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/extrafontdb/fontmap/fonttable.csv
Writing Fontmap to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/extrafontdb/fontmap/Fontmap...
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

I notice that certain fonts are skipped due to a `No FontName` error, whereas others (Arial Black) seem to load fine. After running the font_import, I check to see the fonts available:

```
>   fonts()
 [1] ".Keyboard"             "System Font"           ".SF NS Rounded"        "Andale Mono"          
 [5] "Apple Braille"         "AppleMyungjo"          "Arial Black"           "Arial"                
 [9] "Arial Narrow"          "Arial Rounded MT Bold" "Arial Unicode MS"      "Bodoni Ornaments"     
[13] "Bodoni 72 Smallcaps"   ""                      "Brush Script MT"       "Comic Sans MS"        
[17] "Courier New"           "DIN Alternate"         "DIN Condensed"         "Georgia"              
[21] "Impact"                "Khmer Sangam MN"       "Lao Sangam MN"         "Luminari"             
[25] "Microsoft Sans Serif"  "Tahoma"                "Times New Roman"       "Trattatello"          
[29] "Trebuchet MS"          "Verdana"               "Webdings"              "Wingdings"            
[33] "Wingdings 2"           "Wingdings 3"
```

For my custom fonts, I was provided with a zip file of fonts, and I have uploaded those fonts to my Mac*. The font name is `FreightDisp Pro`, and I can see here that the font is in Mac's Font Book app. However, I would note that the font is not available in my `library/Fonts/` folder, as you can see in the following image:

[image]
[image]

I've tested that the font is available in Microsoft Word, and it is.

And Finally, when I attempt to import the fonts into R, I receive the following error:

```
> font_import(pattern="FreightDisp Pro")
Importing fonts may take a few minutes, depending on the number of fonts and the speed of the system.
Continue? [y/n] y
Scanning ttf files in /Library/Fonts/, /System/Library/Fonts, ~/Library/Fonts/ ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

and I receive this same error when changing the pattern to "National2" as well.

So as I conclude this post, it seems that I also have arrived at the answer to my question, which is that the fonts cannot simply be installed in fontbook, but must also be in the /Library/Fonts folder. I am not sure if I can simply drag + drop the fonts into this folder, or if I can use Font Book to write these fonts into the correct locations. I'm also not sure about the file types, if I can only use `.ttf` files as the post suggests, even though the font files I have are all `.otf`.

### Edit

[Using custom OTF fonts in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058107/using-custom-otf-fonts-in-ggplot2) this post indicates that `.otf` fonts would need to be converted to `.ttf` to use with extrafonts, but that with `showtext`, `.otf` fonts can be used. So I will try to load that library.

Comment: For the loading problem on showtext, install XQuartz: https://github.com/yixuan/showtext/issues/13#issuecomment-332208390.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
In Font Book > Preferences, by switching the preference of the fonts from User to Computer, it ensures that the fonts install into the fonts folder. This solved my problem.